# How do I completely flush dns on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, dns

There's a domain that my PC keeps resolving to `127.0.0.1`, I made sure my etc/hosts file does not contain that domain, and I kept running `ipconfig /flushdns`, but the domain still resolves to `127.0.0.1`. When I run `tracert` on my comp, all I get is:

```
1 <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms www.example.com[127.0.0.1]
```

Here is the result of my `ipconfig /all`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . : CristianPC
   Primary Dns Suffix  : 
   Node Type : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-79-59-34-F7-D2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-E2-30-68-28-79
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-E2-30-68-28-79
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e975:723e:ba97:23f0%4(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.237(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, June 6, 2016 9:36:09 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, June 7, 2016 11:12:18 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 71361072
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-74-DF-E4-F0-79-59-34-F7-D2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-E2-30-68-28-78
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:2c68:87f:cd57:3fab(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c68:87f:cd57:3fab%8(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352321536
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-74-DF-E4-F0-79-59-34-F7-D2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2E10CB81-A9AD-4E2E-B6AD-601FFBAB62FE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

So I'm not sure why the domain still isn't resolving. I'm open to any suggestions, Thanks for any help in advance!!

Comment: edited my question

Comment: The target domain? It could legitimately be resolving to 127.0.0.1 (see http://localtest.me/ and [README](http://readme.localtest.me/))

Comment: It doesn't, It's `bellas-cleaning-service.com`

Answer (score 0):

tracert is calling a library function to get the name associated with 127.0.0.1.  The response you see, www.example.com, could be coming from a couple of places.  (1) LMHOSTS file on local system, (2) NetBIOS broadcast queries if NetBIOS transport is enabled but no WINS servers are known, (3) WINS lookups, or (4) DNS reverse lookups (i.e, think "nslookup 127.0.0.1" or "dig PTR 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa").

The standard response from DNS for this IP is supposed to be "localhost."

Answer (score -1):

This IP address is *localhost*, 127.0.0.1, and is actually coming from some application on your PC that is acting as a server, perhaps a proxy that is redirecting traffic. It might be legitimate, or it could be malware such as [PUM.bad.proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PUM.bad.proxy).

Comment: There is a big difference between where an address goes _to_ and how it is resolved, and I do not see anything in the question that would show the _lookup results_ "coming from some application on your PC". It's perfectly possible for a DNS server to return 127.0.0.1 in response to a domain lookup.